# Allowing people to type their tweets from a form in my site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter

I am trying to make a php page (It's Wordpresss but mostly custom php) that will have a text form that people can type in and send the text to their twitter feed. But I also want to capture the text, process it and do something with it and thank them if they tweet.

This is how I am doing it right now. The home page content is just this

```
<?php
$mess= $_POST['message'];
if($mess=='') {
  include_once('welcome.php');
 } else {
  include_once('thanks.php');
 }
?>
```

welcome.php just makes the form and posts back to this same page with the message. That works fine.

The thanks.php just prints the message on the screen and puts a Twitter tweet button with their message attached. If they click on the button, it pops up a window with their twitter page where they can choose to submit it to Twitter or not.

But how do I know if they actually go through and submit the tweet? I want to thank them for actually tweeting, not just brining up their twitter page and then closing it without tweeting.

Anyone have any idea how to do this? Maybe I am doing this an overly complicated way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't get if user clicks close but you can detect if user tweet after you redirect it to tweet share box,

you should use [Web Intents Javascript Events](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events)

```
tweet

This event will be triggered when the user publishes his tweet within the share box.

twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
    twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {
        alert("yes you shared this on twitter");
    });
});
```